# How to identify the rejected drive in a degraded RAID5?

Tags: linux, raid

I have a 4-drive RAID5 where two drives have bad blocks and the RAID is now degraded and in Read-Only mode.
Reading files and backing up everything went smooth, so no crisis.
My understanding is that one drive has been "kicked out" of the RAID, but which one?
Since I can still read all files, obviously at least 3 drives are still members of the RAID.

Comment: Is this hardware raid?

Comment: No, it's a SW RAID running on an embedded Linux system.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming it's running on mdadm due to the comments.

`mdadm -D` will show you the state of the array including which disk is degraded. I'd advise taking a note of the serial number as this is the only sure fire way to make sure you remove the right disk.

**EDIT** Seems that some versions require you place it into misc mode when querying for details (-D); `mdadm --misc -D` should do the job.

From the comments:

```
Number Major Minor RaidDevice State
 0         8    51          0 active sync /dev/sdd3
 1         8    35          1 active sync /dev/sdc3
 4         8    19          2 spare  rebuilding /dev/sdb3
 3         8     3          3 active sync /dev/sda3
```

It appears sdb failed and is resyncing. Either that, or you've some how swapped out /dev/sdb3 for /dev/sdb in your mdadm config and now it's overwriting the whole disk.

---

If it has some hardware solution instead, you'd need to refer to the hardware manufacturers instructions - normally this would involve booting up and booting into the RAID tool prior to booting the OS, which will detail the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Linux wiz, but I do know how to issue CLI commands. But mdadm -D is not recognized. On my system, the following mdadm commands are available:

mdadm --create
mdadm --assemble
mdadm --build
mdadm --manage
mdadm --misc
mdadm --grow
mdadm --incremental
mdadm --monitor

That's all....

Comment: Ok, so it's appently mdadm --misc -D in some versions....

Comment: Here's the output:
'    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       51        0      active sync   /dev/sdd3
       1       8       35        1      active sync   /dev/sdc3
       4       8       19        2      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdb3
       3       8        3        3      active sync   /dev/sda3
'

Comment: Put the output in the question btw. It looks like sdc3 got out of sync and is rebuilding.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by: Put the output in the question btw.
But no, the way I read this, it looks like sdb3 seems to be rebuilding, don't you agree?

Comment: Whoops yeah, sdb3 - the formatting was lost during the copying. If I was you i'd identify exactly which disk sdb is, and remove it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56382/discussion-between-viking-and-djsmiley2k).